# PowerShell split on "(" throws error: "Not enough )'s."

Tags: powershell

I've come across a weird "bug" or foible in PowerShell, trying to split a string on "(".  Can anyone tell me what's going on, and if there is an easy work-around?

Here's the code:

```
$description = 'Get-ParsedData($Data)'
$description -split "("
```

Result:

```
parsing "(" - Not enough )'s.
At line:1 char:1
+ $description -split "("
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

I've tried using `'('` as well as `"("`, and also

```
$description -split [char]0x0028
```

All result in the same error message: `parsing "(" - Not enough )'s.`

In the end I got around the problem with the following code, which works:

```
$description.SubString(0, $description.IndexOf('('))
```

However, I'm still curious as to why I was getting the original error and whether there is a simple work-around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-split` is a regular expression operator, and `(` needs to be escaped (`\(`):

```bsh
$description -split "\("
```

The error message "Not enough )'s" might seem strange at first, but the reason `(` needs to be escaped in regular expressions is that parentheses are used for *grouping constructs*:

```
PS C:\> 'abc' -split '(b)'
a
b
c
```

In the example above, we split on `b`, but "capture" it's value by enclosing it in `()`.

So when you pass the string `"("` as a pattern, the regex engine sees it and goes "that `(` is the start of a capture group", and since it can't find a corresponding `)`, it throws that error.

You can also use the `[regex]::Escape()` method to automatically escape any literal character in a regex pattern:

```
$splitPattern = [regex]::Escape("(")
$description -split $splitPattern
```

---

Alternatively, use the `String.Split()` method which only does simple substring replacement (and `(` therefore doesn't need escaping):

```
$description.Split("(")
```